# Is this a safe way to identify users connecting to a chat server?

Tags: authentication, php, cookies

Before I start, all information will go over HTTPS.

So, my website is basically like a forum with the authentication part finished and working. This forum has a real time chat application that sends and receives information from a Node.js server. I want people to only be able to send information if logged in, and only from their account.

So I'm planning on doing it this way:

1. User logs in (the forum not the chat client)
2. PHP sets a cookie with a security token that is a randomly generated HEX string (using the function mcrypt_create_iv, with a random length between 15 and 22 characters)
3. The token is also saved into a MySQL database, along with the user ID
4. When the user sends a message through chat, his user ID will also be sent, along with his security token
5. The Node.js server will compare the security token in the database to the user ID, and if they match, the user will be able to chat

Is this a good security scheme, if not why and how can i improve it? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should ensure that your session token is random and at least 128 bits. Aside from that you just basically send a session token and a user id. To be fair, only your session token should be needed to identify a user since it is unique. Ensure also that you destroy the session token after the user logs out. Aside from that it seems similar to any other login scheme.